# Unexpected Always On Availability groups failover happening--- databases changing to resolving

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I recently had done a SQL patch on a two node SQL availability group of SQL Server 2012. Everything went well as far as I can tell. Now two days after the patch unexpected failover happened. Then today as well unexpected failover happened.

For a temporary period, the primary of the availability group goes in to resolving state and forces it into failover to resume data movement as normal.

Now, I am not sure if this is anything related to the patch. Because the error logs show other issues. Here are the logs from the two times this happened.

> Date      6/11/2018 4:40:06 AM Log        SQL Server (Current - 6/11/2018
>   2:25:00 PM) Source        Logon Message Error: 983, Severity: 14, State: 1.
>
> Date      6/11/2018 4:40:06 AM Log        SQL Server (Current - 6/11/2018
>   2:25:00 PM) Source        Logon Message Unable to access database
>   'accounting' because its replica role is RESOLVING which does not
>   allow connections. Try the operation again later. Date        6/11/2018
>   4:40:06 AM Log        SQL Server (Current - 6/11/2018 2:25:00 PM)
>
> And today Date        6/14/2018 3:13:47 PM Log        SQL Server (Current -
>   6/14/2018 3:14:00 PM) Source      spid6s Message SQL Server has
>   encountered 1 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15
>   seconds to complete on file [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\EveriT31_Park.mdf] in database
>   [EveriT31_Parx] (21).  The OS file handle is 0x0000000000000B00.  The
>   offset of the latest long I/O is: 0x00000002750000
>
> Date      6/14/2018 3:14:04 PM Log        SQL Server (Current - 6/14/2018
>   3:14:00 PM) Source        spid127 Message Error: 18056, Severity: 20, State:
>   46.
>
> Date      6/14/2018 3:14:04 PM Log        SQL Server (Current - 6/14/2018
>   3:14:00 PM) Source        spid127 Message The client was unable to reuse a
>   session with SPID 127, which had been reset for connection pooling.
>   The failure ID is 46. This error may have been caused by an earlier
>   operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations
>   immediately before this error message. Date       6/14/2018 3:14:05 PM
>   Log       SQL Server (Current - 6/14/2018 3:14:00 PM)

The AG is set for automatic failover but the alwayson group is not really changing roles. After these episodes, the primary remains primary and the secondary remains secondars.

Every log I look at the first error I get is either the I/O issue or connection pool error (Error: 18056, Severity: 20, State: 46.). I hesitate to say the problem is really that. I don't think it is related with the SQL patch I just did. I don't see anything that is related to it and I want to rule that one out.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing these? I looked at some articles, but none gave me a clear answer.

Comment: Are you set for 'Automatic failover'?  [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_pfe_blog/2013/04/08/sql-2012-alwayson-availability-groups-automatic-failover-doesnt-occur-or-does-it-a-look-at-the-logs/) might help.

Comment: The errors you posted are what I call the victims of the root cause of issue.  Logon failure occurred because databases in resolving state are inaccessible. I/O issues seem to be disk related or performance issue and session had to reset connection pooling is due to the failover. I would start looking at the AG dashboard, XEvents, cluster logs, event logs for further analysis. I bet you would find your root cause from these logs.

Comment: it is set for automatic failover but the alwayson group is not really changing roles. After these episodes, the primary remains primary and the secondary remains secondars. @samosql that is the real problem i am having. Every log i look at the first error i get is either the I/O issue or connection pool error (Error: 18056, Severity: 20, State: 46.). I hesistate to say the problem is really that. I don't think it is related with the sql patch i just did. i don't see anything that is related to it and I want to rule that one out.

Comment: In order to rule out SQL patching as the issue, check your setup bootstrap logs (summary.txt & detail.txt). These files would give you more details on the patching process and if actually everything was completed/successful. It would not hurt either to check MSDN for your current SQL 2012 patch level for known bug issues with AG. How is your cluster health? Do you see any issues on the cluster itself from WSFC manager? Since you know when this issue started, i suggest you check your cluster log (note timezone is UTC). You can post your cluster log to question and I will not mind looking at it.

Comment: Are these servers virtual machines?  If yes, check the VM infrastructure to see if there were snapshots or migrations done at those times.  When a VM snapshot is taken, it pauses the VM, and if it pauses too long, a failover will occur.  This can occur during VM-based backups and migration of the VM to other hosts.

Answer (score 3):

> it is set for automatic failover but the alwayson group is not really changing roles. After these episodes, the primary remains primary and the secondary remains secondars.

I've seen this pattern (PRIMARY -> RESOLVING for a brief period -> PRIMARY, and the same for the SECONDARY) before.  In my case, we were using a file share witness as a third node for quorum.  When this "not failover" happened, it was because the server where the file share witness lived had been taken down for maintenance.

Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) uses a process called the Resource Hosting Subsystem (RHS) to monitor the health of resources in the cluster.  This includes both AG nodes, and in my case the file share witness resource.

While the AG (and cluster) can stay up and running with just the two AG nodes, after the file share witness has been down for 5 minutes, a process called RHS Recovery is started.  You can read more about that here: [Understanding how Failover Clustering Recovers from Unresponsive Resources](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clustering/2013/01/24/understanding-how-failover-clustering-recovers-from-unresponsive-resources/)

If all your resources are hosted in the same RHS process (which is the default behavior), this will cause that "blip" in AG availability while the RHS.exe process is restarted.

Normally after one failure, the problematic resource should be automatically marked as "SeparateMonitor" started up in it's own RHS.exe process (so that it doesn't continue to cause problems for your other cluster resources).  So I'm surprised this happened more than once, but maybe someone changed the setting back, or the behavior is different for different resources or Windows versions.

You can check if that setting is on, or set it manually, in the Cluster Manager.  Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of file share witness in cluster manager]

Anyway, this problem, and especially your comment, sounded very familiar to me so I thought I'd share the experience in case it helps you or others.

I blogged in detail about the troubleshooting process I used for this situation here: [Troubleshooting an AG Failure](https://www.joshthecoder.com/2018/12/03/always-run-rhs-in-separate-process.html)

You should see evidence that RHS Recovery is the root cause of your problem by pulling the cluster log (run the `Get-ClusterLog` PowerShell command) and checking for messages around the time of your AG blip that mention "DeadlockMonitor", which is what checks "down" resources and initiates the recovery process.

Comment: I expect that OP's problem root cause lies in the malfunction of whatever hard drive that hosted C: on the primary cluster node. However this bit of info is pretty helpful as well.

Comment: @Vesper The leap from "slow I/O" error to "malfunctioning disk" is pretty large.  See a discussion about some of the numerous reasons that error could pop up here (especially Sean's answer, as a MSFT employee): [Slow checkpoint and 15 second I/O warnings on flash storage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233705/slow-checkpoint-and-15-second-i-o-warnings-on-flash-storage)

Answer (score -2):

In case you need a failover to happen if your primary SQL Server instance experiences a slow disk read or something, you can try the approach explained here: [Configure a flexible automatic failover policy for an AAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-flexible-automatic-failover-policy?view=sql-server-ver15). Exactly, you can set the `FAILURE_CONDITION_LEVEL` AAG parameter higher than default (3, corresponds to "any critical server error"), most likely to 5 which corresponds to "any failover-able error" as described in the link.

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP AG1 SET (FAILURE_CONDITION_LEVEL = 5);
```

The root cause of that problem you describe is possibly a malfunction of your C: drive hardware, because long reads usually are a sign of disk problems before data loss starts happening.